# Reading file metadata in nodejs with ffmetadata and fs returns undefined

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fs

I cant seem to get this right. I am attempting to read a file's metadata (title) with ffmetadata via a loop on the folder using fs. I would then like to push those properties into an object array called files. If I place the push method inside the ffmetadata, it throws a "push is not a function" error. If I place the push method outside ffmetadata, but inside readdirSync, the object gets created, but the titles are undefined.

I think I'm running into a asynchronous issue or a variable scope issue? I've place several Console.logs over this and the return from the metadata returns after code that comes well after this section.

Any help is appreciated.

```
var path = './AudioFiles/'
var files = [];
var fTitle

//Read list of files
fs.readdirSync(path).forEach((file) => {
    ffmetadata.read(path + file, function(err, data){
        if (err) console.error("Error reading metadata", err);
        else {
            fTitle = data.title
        }
    })
    files.push({name:file.replace('.mp3',''),title:fTitle})
})
```

This is what I am receiving:

```
files = [{name:"myFile1",title:undefined},{name:"myFile2",title:undefined}...]
```

I am expecting the below results:

```
files = [{name:"myFile1",title:"myFile1Title"},{name:"myFile2",title:"myFile2Title"}...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs across this, I figured it out. It was an asynchronous issue.

```
   //Get Metadata
    function getTitles(path, fName){
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                ffmetadata.read(path + fName, function(err, data){
                    if (err) console.error("Error reading metadata", err);
                    else {
                        resolve({name:fName,title:data.title});
                    }
                })
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    function getFiles() {
        var path = './AudioFiles/'
        var files = '';
        const promises = [];
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach((file) => {
            files += file + ',';
        })
        files = files.substring(0,files.length - 1).split(',')

         for(i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
             promises.push(getTitles(path, files[i]))
         }

         Promise.all(promises)
            .then((results) => {
                //Do Stuff Here
                console.log(results)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                //Handle errors here
            });
    }

    //Call our function
    getFiles();
    return;
```